# Some code of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

The code need to send to the function an int **must to send just int** and show the changes after the function. so I tried this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int number = 0;
    printf("Please enter some number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("the number that you entered: %d\n", number);
    inc(number);
    printf("After the 'inc' function, your number is: %d\n", number);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
/*
*/
void inc(int x)
{
    int* px = &x;
    *px= *px+1;
}
```

it's prints just the same number and doesn't change at all. help?

Comment: You need to pass the address and change the value from the function.

Comment: No offense, please re-read a basic C book, pointers chapter first, please.

Comment: The `x` inside `inc` is a copy

Answer (score 3):

you must pass the parameter as a pointer

```
void inc(int *px)
{
    *px= *px+1;
}
```

in your code you are just modifying the functions local copy of x

Comment: And it would be called as `inc(&number)` from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

A hacktacularly terrible hackaround:

```
inc((int)&number);

// ...

void inc(int n)
{
    ++*(int*)n;
}
```

Don't do this. It won't work on all but certain archaic architectures.

Comment: Will it not work on any arch. where ints and pointers can be cast 'safely', (no, I'm not advocating it 'cos of teh nasty hackkiness, as you say:)?